# How can I overlay by-group plot elements to ggplot2 facets?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My question has to do with facetting. In my example code below, I look at some facetted scatterplots, then try to overlay information (in this case, mean lines) on a per-facet basis.

The tl;dr version is that my attempts fail. Either my added mean lines compute across all data (disrespecting the facet variable), or I try to write a formula and R throws an error, followed by incisive and particularly disparaging comments about my mother.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Let's pretend we're exploring the relationship between a car's weight and its
# horsepower, using some sample data
p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = hp), data = mtcars)
print(p)

# Hmm. A quick check of the data reveals that car weights can differ wildly, by almost
# a thousand pounds.
head(mtcars)

# Does the difference matter? It might, especially if most 8-cylinder cars are heavy,
# and most 4-cylinder cars are light. ColorBrewer to the rescue!
p <- p + aes(color = factor(cyl))
p <- p + scale_color_brewer(pal = "Set1")
print(p)

# At this point, what would be great is if we could more strongly visually separate
# the cars out by their engine blocks.
p <- p + facet_grid(~ cyl)
print(p)

# Ah! Now we can see (given the fixed scales) that the 4-cylinder cars flock to the
# left on weight measures, while the 8-cylinder cars flock right. But you know what
# would be REALLY awesome? If we could visually compare the means of the car groups.
p.with.means <- p + geom_hline(
                      aes(yintercept = mean(hp)),
                      data = mtcars
         )
print(p.with.means)

# Wait, that's not right. That's not right at all. The green (8-cylinder) cars are all above the
# average for their group. Are they somehow made in an auto plant in Lake Wobegon, MN? Obviously,
# I meant to draw mean lines factored by GROUP. Except also obviously, since the code below will
# print an error, I don't know how.
p.with.non.lake.wobegon.means <- p + geom_hline(
                                       aes(yintercept = mean(hp) ~ cyl),
                                       data = mtcars
                                     )
print(p.with.non.lake.wobegon.means)
```

There *must* be some simple solution I'm missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean something like this:

```
rs <- ddply(mtcars,.(cyl),summarise,mn = mean(hp))

p + geom_hline(data=rs,aes(yintercept=mn))
```

It might be possible to do this within the `ggplot` call using `stat_*`, but I'd have to go back and tinker a bit. But generally if I'm adding summaries to a faceted plot I calculate the summaries separately and then add them with their own `geom`.

**EDIT**

Just a few expanded notes on your original attempt. Generally it's a good idea to put `aes` calls in `ggplot` that will persist throughout the plot, and then specify different data sets or aesthetics in those `geom`'s that differ from the 'base' plot. Then you don't need to keep specifying `data = ...` in each `geom`.

Finally, I came up with a kind of clever use of `geom_smooth` to do something similar to what your asking:

```
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars,aes(x = wt, y = hp, colour = factor(cyl))) + 
    facet_grid(~cyl) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(se=FALSE,method="lm",formula=y~1,colour="black")
```

The horizontal line (i.e. constant regression eqn) will only extend to the limits of the data in each facet, but it skips the separate data summary step.

Comment: so in your strategy, summary by-grop data is computed separately by ddply and then handed to the geom_hline() function, whereas I had been trying to force geom_hline to just accept summarizing formulae. Your workflow makes sense.

Comment: Thanks...see my edit for an alternate way to accomplish something similar (at least, in this case). Generally, the workflow you describe is a good idea.

Comment: I like your "clever use of `geom_smooth()`, but I'm confused again. Why is `geom_smooth()` respecting each facet? Does it have to do with your specified formula of `formula = y ~ 1`?

Comment: No; that's what I was trying to explain about setting the `data` and `aes` values in the original `ggplot` call. Calling `ggplot()` with no arguments means you're sort of starting from scratch with `geom`. In your case, I think the confusion comes from the order `ggplot` does things in: first it evaluates `mean(hp)` and *then* passes it off to any faceters. That's why you couldn't get `geom_hline` to respect your faceting; `ggplot` didn't know about the faceting when it calculated the mean. (But I'm speculating a bit here...)